# Omni.ja takes to much memory?

Tags: firefox, memory-usage

Recently I noticed my laptop freezes and I can't do anything unless I force reboot it with power button. This time I saw my memory usage increasing on indicator panel.

So I had a look at system monitor and I saw a couple or omni.ja processes each one taking about 900mb now i see why it keeps freezing.

I did a search and found out it's related to Firefox browser But I did not find any fix for it.

Are there any solution for this this?

[image: screenshot showing a list of processes]
[image: screenshot showing the opened files for one of the Web Content processes]

Comment: After a clean reboot, open Firefox, click on *Help > Restart with Add-ons Disabled …*. Does *omni.ja* misbehave now?

Comment: @DKBose Hi.  I did looks like yeah it fixd the issue. But i need my addons

Comment: if an addon misbehaves the only fix is to disable it and post a question about it on the website where the addon is from. You will not be able to fix it unless you can get into the source, re-code that part and use that fix. Better to leave that to the creator of the addon

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks i was mostly worried. Thought maybe im being hacked or my information getting high jacked. do u have ny suggestion for maximum security on a web browser?